# Creating a script that will pull in a particular file from each dependency of a Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to achieve the following - 
I have a rails server that has multiple dependent gems. I am trying to see if there is a script that can be run on application initialization, that would look for a file,in a certain location in each of the dependent gems. 
I am trying to achieve something similar to what sprockets does during the precompilation process (where it would get the js and css files in the app/assets folder of each of the servers dependent gems and put them in the public folder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rake task that can assist with that:

```
task :copy_file_to_public, [:path] do |task, args|
  path = args[:path]
  raise(ArgumentError, "#{path} doesnt exist") unless File.exists?(path)
  file_name = path.split("/")[-1]
  public_path = "./public/#{file_name}"
  raise(ArgumentError, "#{file_name} already exists in public") if File.exists?(public_path)
  `cp "#{path}" "#{public_path}"`
end
```

From shell:

```
rake copy_file_to_public[/path/to/file]
```

Comment: Thanks max for the answer. When I run this rake task in the context of my app server, would it actually go through each gem dependency of the server and get the file?

Comment: No. It copies a single file into public. I was just showed how you can do she'll scripting in ruby

Comment: My main issue is how do I go through each dependent gem and get the file

Comment: well, you are already going in and manually adding each gem to the gemfile. Is it really so much work to list their assets in `application.js` and `application.css`?

Comment: I agree. However, that is something which I don't want to do. I want to see if there is a way this can be done on the application server level so that each gem owner does not need to add it to the application.js and css